# Azure Media service live streaming using raspberry pi 2

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, live-streaming, raspberry-pi2, azure-media-services

I have tried to stream a video from my raspberry pi 2 using a webcam using the tutorial here http://gtrifonov.com/2015/07/02/streaming-live-video-from-raspberrypi-to-azure-media-services/. 
Using ffmpeg, I am running this in Ubuntu mate terminal:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -r 30 -s 640×480 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -acodec libfaac -ab 48k -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 500k -r 30 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -sc_threshold 0 -f flv $INGESTURI
```

Now, to see the video is streaming I am using PLAY PREVIEW URL from the azure portal. It works, interrupted, at a very fast speed for about 5 second and than it stops with an error 
After that I try to play the video again and I can see the one that was streaming before the error and than it breaks again.
From the Ubuntu mate I can tell the streaming is working fine: connection established and I can see the frames being sent.

```
fps=7.9 q=28 bitrate = 500 kbits
```

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hello do you have constant fps of 7.9? Preview have less interruptions with higher fps. From my experimentation i was targeting fps > 25.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this thread
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ec584807-2f17-4723-80f9-8a0ae203453d/stream-to-azure-media-service-from-ffmpeg-stream-can-not-be-played?forum=MediaServices

Azure media player do not play videos that does not contain audio.
So using following player i was able to watch the video.
http://smf.cloudapp.net/healthmonitor